# How to autofocus/highlight a selectlist when nothing is selected after a button is clicked using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a button and a selectlist,what I want to do is highlight/autofocus the selectlist when nothing is selected after a button is clicked an error message does show when nothing is selected,but the selectlist doesn't get highlighted/autofocus.This is my code
HTML:

```
<div ng-app=ngAppModule ng-form="MyForm">
     <select id="categorylist"  class="col-md-11" name="CategoryId" ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories" required="">
     <option value=""></option>
     </select> 
<button type="button" ng-click="Model.StopDowntimeEvent(MyForm)" ng-confirm-click="Are you sure you want to Stop the Downtime?" class="btn btn-danger btn-primary" >Stop Downtime</button>

    <div class="validation-error col-md-2"
       ng-show="(MyForm.CategoryId.$dirty || invalidSubmitAttempt) && MyForm.CategoryId.$error.required">
        Please select a category.
  </div>
```

JS:

```
ngAppModule.controller('DowntimeController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.Model = new Model($http);

    $scope.Model.StopDowntimeEvent = function (ngForm) {
        if (ngForm.$invalid) {
            $scope.invalidSubmitAttempt = true;
            return;
        }
        $scope.Model.StopDowntime();
    }
}]);
```

CSS:

```
.validation-error {
    color: red;
    font-weight:bold;
    width: 250px;
    text-align: left;
}
select.ng-dirty.ng-invalid, select.ng-invalid.invalid.invalidSubmitAttempt, select.ng-invalid.had-focus {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Comment: can you prepare a plunkr for your code ?

Comment: I'd suggest an angular directive for DOM manipulation, in this case: `element.focus()`.

Comment: @Yasser I would love to but am running the application on the intranet and my data in stored in the local database

Comment: More or less is something like this http://plnkr.co/edit/LbHRBB?p=preview